# Запрос к MongoDB с фильтром

Tags: mongodb, запрос, nosql

Есть таблица вида:

```
_id | model | speed | price |
```

Надо составить запрос и вывести среднюю скорость по моделям, цена которых выше 2000.

Пытался сделать так:

```
db.laptop_full.find({price: {$gt: 2000}}).aggregate([{$group: {_id: "Laptop", avg_speed: {$avg: "$speed"}}}])
```

но выдает ошибку, я так понимаю - нельзя *aggregate* вызывать после *find*

Пытался еще сделать через `db.laptop_full.aggregate()` вставляя туда `$filter` и `$group`, но ничего не выходит и не очень то понимаю как надо.. **Подскажите запрос, пожалуйста**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему с использованием `$match`. Запрос выглядит так:

```
db.laptop.aggregate(
     [
          {"$match": {"price": {$gt:2000}}}, 
          {$group: {_id: "laptops", avg_speed: {$avg: "$speed"}}}
     ]
)
```